How to Keep Pinned Projects from Being Cleared in Visual Studio 2022 Using ClearRecent
I’m trying to figure out how to keep pinned projects from being cleared when using the ClearRecent project in Visual Studio 2022. I’ve noticed that the current implementation doesn’t seem to support keeping pinned projects, and I couldn’t find any relevant information online—most resources I found pertained to older versions of Visual Studio.
Has anyone successfully managed to retain pinned projects while using ClearRecent? If so, could you point me in the right direction or share any insights on how to achieve this?
